# Search Result Listing Get index of an item using Scriban

Tags: sxa, sxa-search, scriban

I have a `Search Result Listing` Variant created using Scriban. This will render a card from each of the items got from the `scope query`. However, I want to get the index of items at the scriban template.

Here is my current Search Result Listing

```
<div class="search-result-card" data-item-index="{{i_item.index}}">
  ...

</div>
```

Lets say my `Scope` is returning 5 items, Basically I want to get the index of the current item and put it on a `data-attribute`. But `i_item` context that is exposed at scriban is pointing to current item.

Is there no way to get that index?

Sorry if my explanation is a it confusing.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to do it because variant is used to generate each result separately not the whole list.

This is a place where items from index are prepared

`Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController`

```
list = (IEnumerable<Result>) source.Select<SearchItem, Result>((Func<SearchItem, Result>) (i => new Result(i, variant))).ToList<Result>();
```

`Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Models.Result`

Inside `Result` model output HTML is created this way.

```
this.Html = service.RenderVariant(variant, searchItem.Item);
```

As you can see only variant and single item are passed to service thus there is no way to tell the index.

### Solution - workaround

Not ideal because you cannot do it via variant but if you really need it I would suggest doing it in JS.

Not sure which one will work better for you:

- try to attach to event responsible for binding search results (`XA.component.search.vent.on("results-loaded", this.resultsLoaded.bind(this));` in `component-search-results.js`
- override render function in `component-search-results.js`

Comment: Still a Huge Thanks for this! At the very least this helped me to get on the right track! Thanks mate!